# Every continuous function $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow X$ is null-homotopic

Tags: homotopy-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow X$ be continuous and $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow X$ a constant map with image $\{x_0\}$.
For the proof, I thought that we can define $F:[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^n$ with $F(s,x)=(1-s)f(x)+sx_0$. Is this the homotopy we're looking for? It seems rather easy, or am I missing something?

Comment: Well: if $f(x)$ and $x_0$ are the elements of a generic topological space $X$ and $s\in [0,1]$, what's $(1-s)f(x)+sx_0$ ?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli That's the homotopy function, it satisfies $F(0,x)=f(x)$ and $F(1,x)=x_0$ and it is continuous

Comment: As of now, no. $F$ is not even defined: what's the sum of two elements of a topological space?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli How can I prove the homotopy otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need $x_0$ to be in the same path component as $Im f$

$F(t,x) := f(tx)$ gives you a homotopy between $f$ and the constant map at $f(0) \in X$. Now take a path  $h: [0,1] \to X$ from $f(0)$ to $x_0$. Define a functtion $H(t,x) : = h(t)$. This gives you the homotopy between the constant map at $f(0)$ and $g$. So you are done by transitivity of homotopy.